# How to navigate through contentEditable Table using "tab"

Tags: jquery

I am very new with java script and jQuery and managed to create a editable table that will do some calculations I needed to do. Problem is, when I use tab, I would like it to move the cursor to next cell.

This is first time posting here as well so please bear with me if I sound ridiculous!

Here is how my html part of the code looks.

```
<div id = "showTable" contentEditable="true" tabindex="0">
<table id="tbl" width = "850px" border="1">
    <tbody>
    <th>Date Worked</th>
    <th>Start</th>
    <th>Meal break</th>
    <th>End</th>
    <th>Hourly Wage</th>
    <th>Gross Earnings</th>
    <th>Pay Date</th>
    </tbody>

 </table>
</div>
```

After, in the javascript, I have function (which I found online) that will create dynamic table.

```
function createDynamicTable(tbody, rows, cols) 
{
    if (tbody == null || tbody.length < 1) return;
    for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) 
    {
        var trow = $("<tr>");
        for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) 
        {
            if(c == 0)
            {
                var dateWorked = "mm/dd/yyyy" ;
                $("<td>")
                        .addClass("tableCell")
                        .text(dateWorked)
                        .data("col", c)
                        .appendTo(trow);
                col[counter] = dateWorked;
                counter++;
                masterCounter++;
            }
            else if (c == 1)
            {
                var startTime = "h:mm AM/PM";
                $("<td>")
                        .addClass("tableCell")
                        .text(startTime)
                        .data("col", c)
                        .appendTo(trow);

                col[counter] = startTime;
                counter++;
                masterCounter++;
            }
            else if (c == 2)
            {
                var mealBreakMin = "time in minutes";
                $("<td>")
                        .addClass("tableCell")
                        .text(mealBreakMin)
                        .data("col", c)
                        .appendTo(trow);

                col[counter] = mealBreakMin;
                counter++;
                masterCounter++;
            }
            else if (c == 3)
            {
                var endTime = "h:mm AM/PM";
                $("<td>")
                        .addClass("tableCell")
                        .text(endTime)
                        .data("col", c)
                        .appendTo(trow);

                col[counter] = endTime;
                counter++;
                masterCounter++;
            }
            else if (c == 4)
            {
                var hourlyWage = "$-.--";
                $("<td>")
                        .addClass("tableCell")
                        .text(hourlyWage)
                        .data("col", c)
                        .appendTo(trow);

                col[counter] = hourlyWage;
                counter++;
                masterCounter++;
            }

            if(r == 6)
            {
                if (c == 5)
                {
                    var grossPay = "$-.--";
                    $("<td>")
                    .addClass("tableCell")
                    .text(grossPay)
                    .data("col", c)
                    .appendTo(trow);

                    col[counter] = hourlyWage;
                    counter++;
                    masterCounter++;
                }

                else if (c == 6)
                {
                    var payDate = "mm/dd/yyyy";
                    $("<td>")
                    .addClass("tableCell")
                    .text(payDate)
                    .data("col", c)
                    .appendTo(trow);

                    col[counter] = hourlyWage;
                    counter++;
                    masterCounter++;
                }
            }

        }
        trow.appendTo(tbody);
    }
    counter = 0;
}
```

Now, on jQuery part, I tried something like

```
$(".tableCell").live('click', function(e) {
    document.execCommand('selectAll', false, null);
});
```

Even though my goal is to tab to next cell, I first tried the following.

I thught above code will highlight one part of the cell only. However, it will highlight entire cell. I did look around the web but could not find exact answer where how their table was made was similar to mine.

It would be awesome if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Is the structure of the table supposed to be editable?  Or just the fields inside of it?  If just the content of each cell, I'd suggest creating your table WITHOUT contentEditable and instead opt for using <input type="text /> tags which you can then tab between by default.

Comment: EDIT: I believe I can not just do input type = "text" since the reason I created the function was so user can click a button and it will create additional table to write stuff into. Within the table, it is performing calculation based on user's input as well so I am not sure how this will work. If you can give some example with my code, it would be great!

Comment: could you post the part of the code where you are using the variables: col, counter, and masterCounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate what I had suggested, I put together a jsFiddle to see if this matches what you are after:

http://jsfiddle.net/u4pAg/2/

Just a few `<tr>` with 7 `<td>` to match your `<th>` in your example.  Each of the `<td>` contains an `<input type="text" />` tag with the default value based on what was in your `createDynamicTable()` function.

I also added a stitch of jQuery... first, I am looping through all the inputs and store their ddefault value using jQuery's .data() method (http://api.jquery.com/data/) for later use.  I remove the default value on focus (but only if it is still the default value).  If it is not the default value, it keeps that content there and just selects the content for easy replacing/updating (can be removed out if you don't like the auto selecting). On blur, I check if the input is left blank and if so, I add back the previously stored default value.  I through in some CSS in there as well for some visual interest.

EDIT------

If in your createDynamicTable() function, you update the points where you are setting the .text() for your `<td>` and instead set the .html() to include an input tag instead of just text, it turn out something like this (I just commented out the vars that it was looking for that were not defined, per my comment to your post):

http://jsfiddle.net/u4pAg/4/

Comment: Thank you very much for you help, I have added the pre-source code in the link below. Again, thank you. I would have never though of useing input=text instead of table. Since all the calculation I have was initially with a table (and worked), if I can find a way to use the input user writes and somehow put in an array, I believe I wouldnt have to change around the calculation code so much and would still work.     http://pastebin.com/jZbuc5Xp

Comment: After editing the code with your guidance, I was able to have the "table" adding on it after pressing "add more week" button! Now just to get the calculations to work! I will keep looking for solution as well. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same requirement, where the tab & shift-tab keys must be allowed to navigate a contentEditable table in a Kendo UI Editor.

In this context, adding input elements to each cell wouldn't have been feasible, since the values of any embeded form elements would be lost when saving the editor's content.

The solution I discovered utilizes the [Window Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection), upon capture of the keydown event.  Please see a working proof-of-concept here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dperish/30nh0wc3/

This method should be generic enough to work with any 3rd party editor controls as well as raw contentEditable regions.  At the time of this post, it appears to work perfectly in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, IE & Edge.

```js
/**
 * Enables tabbing/shift-tabbing between contentEditable table cells
 * @param {Window} win - Active window context.
 * @param {Event} e - jQuery Event object for the keydown that fired.
 */
function tabifyEditableTable(win, e) {

  if (e.keyCode !== 9) {
    return false;
  }

  var sel;

  if (win.getSelection) {

    sel = win.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {

      var textNode = null;

      if (!e.shiftKey) {
        textNode = (sel.focusNode.nodeName === "TD") 
          ? (sel.focusNode.nextSibling != null) 
            ? sel.focusNode.nextSibling 
            : (sel.focusNode.parentNode.nextSibling != null) 
              ? sel.focusNode.parentNode.nextSibling.childNodes[0] 
              : null 
            : (sel.focusNode.parentNode.nextSibling != null) 
              ? sel.focusNode.parentNode.nextSibling 
              : (sel.focusNode.parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling != null) 
                ? sel.focusNode.parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling.childNodes[0] 
                : null;
      } else {
        textNode = (sel.focusNode.nodeName === "TD") 
          ? (sel.focusNode.previousSibling != null) 
            ? sel.focusNode.previousSibling 
            : (sel.focusNode.parentNode.previousSibling != null) 
                ? sel.focusNode.parentNode.previousSibling.childNodes[sel.focusNode.parentNode.previousSibling.childNodes.length - 1] 
                : null 
              : (sel.focusNode.parentNode.previousSibling != null) 
                ? sel.focusNode.parentNode.previousSibling 
                : (sel.focusNode.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling != null) 
                  ? sel.focusNode.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling
          .childNodes[sel.focusNode.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling.childNodes.length - 1] 
                  : null;
      }

      if (textNode != null) {
        sel.collapse(textNode, Math.min(textNode.length, sel.focusOffset + 1));
        if (textNode.textContent != null) {
          sel.selectAllChildren(textNode);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return true;
      }
      
    }
    
  }

  return false;

}
```

For support in older versions or IE or Safari, you may need to fall-back on [Range](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html) objects to provide the same functionality.